# Why the BufferedGraphics is slow in drawing?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using `BufferedGraphics` on `Form_Paint` event. It draws my required graphic but its too slow. Kindly give me the hints to solve this problem or any suggestions for better drawing techniques for the quick response.

```
BufferedGraphicsContext currentContext;
BufferedGraphics myBuffer;
// Gets a reference to the current BufferedGraphicsContext
currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current;
// Creates a BufferedGraphics instance associated with Form1, and with 
// dimensions the same size as the drawing surface of Form1.
myBuffer = currentContext.Allocate(this.CreateGraphics(),
this.DisplayRectangle);
// Draws an ellipse to the graphics buffer.

myBuffer.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\My Pictures\\Pics\\Pic.jpg"), 0, 0);
myBuffer.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, 5, 90, 10, 10);
myBuffer.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Gold, 0, 7, 500, 500);
myBuffer.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Chartreuse, 0, 0, 800, 800);

myBuffer.Render();
```

This is a small example of the `BufferedGraphics`, this works fine, but when the load increases, it slows down.

Comment: Can you post the code in question? It is difficult to give a meaningful answer without seeing the code.

Comment: How slow is it and how fast do you need it? And if you cut out the buffering, does that solve the issue?

Comment: @Henk Holterman, I have a animation whose completion time is 6 second, but after rendering, the time exceed to 12 to 13 second.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use e.Graphics instead of this.CreateGraphics()

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `DoubleBuffered = true` and paint directly on form, it will perform much faster.

Answer (score 0):

As noted you should use:

```
e.Graphics
```

Instead of:

```
this.CreateGraphics()
```

And about this line:

```
new Bitmap("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\My Documents\\My Pictures\\Pics\\Pic.jpg")
```

You are reading the image on every frame render, you should create a Bitmap outside Paint and just refer to it.